# How to access the variable inside a button in a Streamlit frame work?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have three variables, `days`, `date` and `name`; `days` is a slider which takes only integer value, `date` is a date picker and `name` is a string variable.

There is a function called `some_function()` that takes these three variables and returns `result` as output. I am using `Streamlit` framework and I have defined a button called `Submit`, once the `Submit` button is clicked, the function is invoked and returns `result`.

My problem is that I can access the output of the function within the button but I need to access this output outside the button as well for further calculation.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
days = st.slider("No of days", min_value=1, max_value=15, value=1)
date = st.date_input("Select a date: ")
today = datetime.today().date()
name = st.text_input("Enter the name of the country: ")

if st.button("Submit"):
    if date < today:
        st.error("Don't enter past date")
    else:
        result = some_function(name, days, date)
        st.write(result)
```

Comment: Which variable do you want to access outside?

Comment: The output from the function i.e. *result* which I want to access outside, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it this way:

```
days = st.slider("No of days", min_value=1, max_value=15, value=1)
date = st.date_input("Select a date: ")
today = datetime.today().date()
name = st.text_input("Enter the name of the country: ")
result = ""

if st.button("Submit"):
    if date < today:
        st.error("Don't enter past date")
    else:
        result = some_function(name, days, date)
        st.write(result)
print(result)
```

Comment: I am using following code `st.write(result)` outside the `if st.button("Submit):` block then I am getting *NameError: name 'result' is not defined* error.

Comment: Did you declare result outside as mentioned? Can you share full code?

Comment: Hi Suhsant, thanks for your feedback, I forgot to declare the variable outside the `if st.button("Submit):` block, once I have done that I could access it outside the block.

Comment: please like the answer if it solved your issue, It would help others.